# Como ligo o php com o banco de dados desse cadasro?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código de registro é esse:

```
 <form class="register-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="nome"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="senha"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email"/>
    <button>create</button>
    <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="cadastrando.php">Sign In</a></p>
  </form>
  <form class="login-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <button>login</button>
    <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
  </form>
```

Já tentei fazer a conexão com o banco de dados usando esse comando:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Cadastrando...</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "xampp";
$banco = "cadastro";
$conexao = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_errir());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php

$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$senha=$_POST['senha'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, senha, email)
VALUES('$nome', '$senha', '$email')");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Sendo que eu criei o banco de dados todo certinho só q n dá certo. 
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Já começou errado as funções `mysql_` não devem ser usadas, use o MySQLi ou PDO para conexão com o banco.

Answer (score 2):

Voce tem que enviar esse formulario para uma pagina para processar os dados, fazer a consulta à base de dados e aí estabelecer o cadastro.

```
<form action="cadastro.php" name="meuForm" method="POST">
...seu form....
</form>
```

Página PHP - **cadastro.php** 
Nessa página, você tem de guardar os dados dos campos preenchidos pelo utilizador e então fazer a consulta à base de dados.

Pode consultar essa informação: 
http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-create-login-and-signup-form-in-php_377.html